# Issues with pagefooter (CSS & HTML)

Tags: html, css

I have managed to make my pagefooter stay at the bottom, but it overlaps my content. The 100% height on body won't seem to help, and I have looked across the internet for solutions, but none have worked.

My page footer either just stays near the bottom, or sticks to the bottom and overlaps my content when I resize the page. I tried giving my body a height of 100%, my wrapper some bottom padding and min-height of 100% - everything that is online really. I just can't seem to get a solution for my problem.

Would post code, but it is so long... Here is my html simplified:
(note: width class is: width: 100% in CSS as I didn't want to keep repeating myself as I use it on a lot of background elements.)

```
<html>

<body>

<div id="blackBarTop" class= "width">

  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="floatRight">

      <div id="phoneNumber"> <b> PHONE:</b> </div>

      <div id="socialIcons"></div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div id="masthead">

    <div id="logo"></div>

    <div id="search"></div>

    <div id="mainNav"></div>

    <div id "heroImage"></div>

    <div id="content">

      <div id="welcome" class="wrapper">

        <h1>text</h1>
        <p>text</p>


      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<div id="pageFooter" class="width"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Post your CSS also before you get -1.This cannot be answered unless you post CSS.

Comment: You can make a jsfiddle by going here jsfiddle.net . which helps to answer easily.

Answer (score 2):

You should add following thing to your footer CSS:

```
clear:both;
```

I hope you are using `float` in other `<div>` elements. When you use `clear:both`, it will adjust itself to the bottom of the largest element that is lying above it.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your footer height is, take that number and put it here:

```
body {
    padding-bottom: FOOTERHEIGHT;
}
```

Or use margin.  Without your CSS I can't advise one way or the other reliably.

Comment: Glad to help where I can